# How to improve wordpress apereance->menus performance?

Tags: wordpress, apache2, lamp

I am using wordpress, added more than 100 pages in my menu, submenu. 
What configurations for my php.ini or any other server configuration files needed to improve performance of managing menus in wordpress?

```
SELECT `ID` , `post_date` , `post_modified` , `post_parent` , `post_content` , `post_name` , `post_status` , `menu_order`
FROM `test1_posts`
WHERE `post_type` = 'nav_menu_item' AND `post_status` = 'draft'
ORDER BY `test1_posts`.`post_parent` DESC
```

Comment: you can categorize your content.

Comment: I need best options woking with wordpress menu,
 i have more than 200 items to fill to my menu, after 90 menus adding time is more than 1minute per item.

Answer (score 0):

just cache the menu output in your theme.

see this plugin:
https://github.com/ryanhellyer/menu-cache

Caches the menu on each page so you will never lose the "active" class in your menu.

Comment: That idea, do not solve my problem, It is not recommended to use this plugin on huge amount of pages in menu.